# ROS Crashing on macOS X Sierra with JavaScript heap out of memory error

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I'm running the developers edition of Realm Object Server v1.8.3 as a mac app.  I start it with the start-object-server.command.  It has been running fine for a number of days and everything was working really well, but ROS is now crashing within seconds of starting it.

Clearly the issue is with the JavaScript element, but I am not sure what has led to this position, nor how best to recover from this error. I have not created any additional functions, so not adding any NODE.js issues: it's just ROS with half a dozen realms.

The stack dump I get from the terminal session is as below. Any thoughts on recovery steps and how to prevent it happening again would be appreciated.

**Last few GCs**

> 607335 ms: Mark-sweep 1352.1 (1404.9) -> 1351.7 (1402.9) MB, 17.4 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
>     607361 ms: Mark-sweep 1351.7 (1402.9) -> 1351.7 (1367.9) MB, 25.3 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].
>     607376 ms: Mark-sweep 1351.7 (1367.9) -> 1351.6 (1367.9) MB, 15.3 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].

**JS stacktrace**

> Security context: 0x3eb4332cfb39 
>       1: DoJoin(aka DoJoin) [native array.js:~129] [pc=0x1160420f24ad] (this=0x3eb433204381 ,w=0x129875f3a8b1 ,x=3,N=0x3eb4332043c1 ,J=0x3828ea25c11 ,I=0x3eb4332b46c9 )
>       2: Join(aka Join) [native array.js:180] [pc=0x116042067e32] (this=0x3eb433204381 ,w=0x129875f3a8b1
>
> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
>    1: node::Abort() [/Applications/realm-mobile-platform/realm-object-server/.prefix/bin/node]
>    2: node::FatalException(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local, v8::Local) [/Applications/realm-mobile-platform/realm-object-server/.prefix/bin/node]
>    3: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [/Applications/realm-mobile-platform/realm-object-server/.prefix/bin/node]
>    4: v8::internal::Factory::NewRawTwoByteString(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/Applications/realm-mobile-platform/realm-object-server/.prefix/bin/node]
>    5: v8::internal::Runtime_StringBuilderJoin(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/Applications/realm-mobile-platform/realm-object-server/.prefix/bin/node]
>    6: 0x1160411092a7
>   /Applications/realm-mobile-platform/start-object-server.command: line 94: 39828 Abort trap: 6           node "$package/node_modules/.bin/realm-object-server" -c configuration.yml  (wd: /Applications/realm-mobile-platform/realm-object-server/object-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ROS instance has run out of memory. To figure out why it runs out of memory, it would be helpful to see the log file of the server. Can you turn
on the debug level for logging.

If you want to send a log file to Realm, it is better to open an issue for this at https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/issues.

Comment: Whatever the problem was, it hasn't occurred for a number of days now, so I will close the issue at this point.  I will, however, turn on logging so if it does occur again, I can capture the details.